# When should I use KERS?

Tags: f1-2012

So far, I've been using KERS when:

- Starting a medium/big straight line.
- Overtaking.
- Starting a race.

I don't really have any preference on them, so I just use KERS whenever I feel to.

So, when should I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, it's probably best to use KERS for the reasons you stated above.  I would probably defer from using it at the start of a race since you still have the rest of the race to get ahead and win.

In actual Formula One, drivers can only use their KERS for 6.67 seconds a lap.  I don't know if the game follows these restrictions having not played it, but if it does, it would be best to save your KERS for when you need it the most. This could vary depending on where you are at in the race (for instance, is it the last lap and are you neck and neck with the driver in second?).

I would use my KERS after going around a corner, where using my brakes would generate the energy into the KERS for use to gain my speed back.  But other than that, I feel you are using the KERS to the best of its ability already (minus the start of the race part in my opinion).

Here are a few other posts discussing when to use KERS:

- [Steam Forum](https://steamcommunity.com/app/208500/discussions/0/630800447010939919/)
- [Xbox Achievements](http://www.xboxachievements.com/forum/showthread.php?t=331192)

The Steam Forum users said coming out of corners and on straights.  The Xbox Achievements users basically said the same, but stated that they use it when coming out of a corner and headed down a straight.

Comment: In this game, you have a standard amount of it every lap that does not regenerate by breaking, just when starting the next lap.

Comment: That's rather disappointing to hear.  That's not how a real KERS works :/

Comment: I know, but I guess that's how you limit players from abusing it without the *time limitation* as it could look a bit awkward for casual/new players.

Comment: I suppose what I said still applies however.  The only difference being you don't generate KERS as you go.

Comment: That's right, I will wait a bit before making it the answer as it contains a few opnion based statements and would like to know if there's more actual facts on how to use. Thanks anyways :)